# Connect GitHub to my personal domain

Tags: website, domain, web-development, github, node.js

I've created a project in Node.js, and now I want to push it live. I did some Googling and found that I can put my project on GitHub by making a repository, so I created a repository and pushed my project on GitHub. Now I want this to connect with my domain (e.g., www.mydomain.com), but I am stuck because I don't know how to do this.

Please let me know the complete step-by-step procedure for connecting my Node.js app with Sailsjs of GitHub with my domain.

I'll wait for the reply with patience.

Note: I am a beginner, so a brief example would help me a lot.

Comment: At first I was thinking perhaps you just wanted to link to github from your website, but if you actually want to _run_ the project from github, you have the wrong site for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a lot of the pieces in this puzzle. One does not simply 'connect their domain to GitHub'.

1. You need a server
2. Your server needs to be capable of hosting your project
3. You'll need to use [GitHub's webhooks](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-webhooks) to alert the server when changes are commited
4. The server will then need to pull these changes and redeploy, automatically

You might look for some hosting that has this built in.

Maybe others can chime in, but the only one I'm aware of is Microsoft's Azure, which has a pretty simple way of connecting GitHub for automatic deployment. Getting it to deploy a project that wasn't built in Visual Studio however may be a challenge.

Comment: https://www.heroku.com/ is also a good place to look at for free small hosting.